# Get errors when using R package aws.s3

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to s3 with the function `aws.s3::s3write_using()` but it prints an error on the console. This error contains truncated parts so I can't inspect it with the detail I want. How can I save this error (formatted as a list) to an object?

For example:

```
aws.s3::s3write_using(iris, FUN = fwrite, sep = ";", object = "iris", bucket = "non_existing_bucket")
```

Throws an error and prints the following:

```
List of 5
 $ Code      : chr "NoSuchBucket"
 $ Message   : chr "The specified bucket does not exist"
 $ BucketName: chr "non_existing_bucket"
 $ RequestId : chr "N3H55KTQNCFDW8YH"
 $ HostId    : chr "8GyUqcYR0GqjQifuCSOC9Zqc35Be1aE5cfUuDOBFGpb0LzlNQxaIvbvJzfmmxRSXSb7iV7rnv94="
 - attr(*, "headers")=List of 7
  ..$ x-amz-request-id : chr "N3H55KTQNCFDW8YH"
  ..$ x-amz-id-2       : chr "8GyUqcYR0GqjQifuCSOC9Zqc35Be1aE5cfUuDOBFGpb0LzlNQxaIvbvJzfmmxRSXSb7iV7rnv94="
  ..$ content-type     : chr "application/xml"
  ..$ transfer-encoding: chr "chunked"
  ..$ date             : chr "Thu, 06 May 2021 10:17:11 GMT"
  ..$ server           : chr "AmazonS3"
  ..$ connection       : chr "close"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "aws_error"
 - attr(*, "request_canonical")= chr "PUT\n/non_existing_bucket/iris\n\ncontent-length:3867\nhost:s3.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-acl:private\nx-amz-date:202"| __truncated__
 - attr(*, "request_string_to_sign")= chr "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20210506T101611Z\n20210506/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\nf889bc56946eed90f7d83382881ede47d3b8453"| __truncated__
 - attr(*, "request_signature")= chr "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAWLC3MSZDR2UM7O7Q/20210506/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=content-lengt"| __truncated__
NULL
Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : 
  Not Found (HTTP 404).
```

What I need is to save that list to an R object.